# How to update my production database in a django/heroku project with a script

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-models

I want to update a field in my users table on my django project hosted on heroku.

Is there a way I can run a script(if so from where?) using what?

That allows me to update a field in the database? I could do this manually in the django admin but it would take way to long as there are large number of users.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you update the data in your local then make a fixture, commit and push it in your heroku. then do load the data using the terminal

> update data (locally)
>
> make a fixture (manage.py dumpdata)
>
> commit and push to heroku
>
> login via terminal (heroku login)
>
> load the data (heroku run python manage.py loaddata .json)